# comparing column of two input files using awk array

Tags: linux, awk

Can someone assist me on how to get the result below using `awk` or `grep` command

igs811 linus> wc -l icc

```
11 icc

{81580003 PF12}
{90544829 PF10}
{81594316 PF10}
{81580003 PF10}
{70510135 PF10}
{81586919 PF11}
{81580000 PF11}
{81580000 PF11}
{81580000 PF11}
{81597367 PF12}
{70599713 PF12}
```

igs811 linus> wc -l icd

```
11 icd

{81580003 PF12}
{90544829 PF10}
{81594316 PF11}
{81580003 PF11}
{70510135 PF10}
{81586919 PF11}
{81580000 PF11}
{81580000 PF12}
{81580000 PF12}
{81597367 PF10}
{70599713 PF12}
```

(Result file=print only below 5 ICC with the wrong PF on icd so I can  update the database)
Finally, I am updating with only this 5

```
result_txt ={81594316 PF10}
{81580003 PF10}
{81580000 PF11}
{81580000 PF11}
{81597367 PF12}
```

I used below but got a wrong result

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2}; NR!=FNR {print $1,a[$1]}'​ icc icd >Result_file​
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is the input and an example of the exact output you expect? And please format your question with the code `{}` tool

Comment: Would you mind explaining what "print only below 5 ICC with wrong PF on icd so i can update the database " means?

Comment: @guillermochamorro, i added the screenshot kindly check now

Comment: @Onyeka Nwangwu If you want someone to help you, it will help if they can interpret "below 5 ICC with wrong PF on icd" correctly.

Comment: @guillermochamorro pls check now edited

Comment: @suspectus kindly ignore as that is just a description of what is expected on my result. pls check as the file has now been edited

Answer (score 0):

we can get the result using `diff` command

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' icc icd
{81594316 PF10}
{81580003 PF10}
{81580000 PF11}
{81580000 PF11}
{81597367 PF12}
```

Comment: it worked on the few sample number here but when i applied it to about 57 millions of number, it printed out exactly what i have on icc.txt. Kindly assist further

Comment: all ur data must be different then... can u try increasing the input lines step by step

Comment: i have same data on column 1 but some data are difference on column 2  "icd". so i want to match and print out all file on "icc" but with different "PF" on "icd". pls check the expected result file so u understand better. Thanks for kind assistance

Comment: @OnyekaNwangwu I suspect no lines are identical between those two files u have

Comment: Are u sure u have only two columns in both files?